# base64_encode into php string? images in array need to be displayed dynamically

Tags: php, base64, blob

images along with search results are put in $_SESSION then header out to another page when a search query is made.. here i want the images to be echoed out with the title, link, and description of the search.

```
        if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){          
            echo $_SESSION['error'];

        } else      

        { 

            echo ($_SESSION['count']);
              foreach($_SESSION['search_output'] as $value){
                $value['id'];  
                $value['links'];
                $value['title'];
                $value['page_body'];
                $value['thumbs'];


                $id = $value['id'];
                $title = $value['title'];
                $link = $value['links'];
                $body = $value['page_body'];
                $thumbs = $value['thumbs'];

                echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $thumbs ) . '" />';

                $search_output .= " <a href='".$link."'>".$title."</a> - $body<br>";}
}
```

as you can see in the second last line echoing out the images are fine but they show up next to each other. however i want the images to be displayed next to the search results one by one. if i put the whole string in the $search_output like:

```
$search_output .= "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,\' . base64_encode( $thumbs ) . \'\" /><a href='".$link."'>".$title."</a> - $body<br>";}
```

it doesn't work.. how can i make it so that the images will be displayed next to the search results *(making this search engine is driving me nuts!)*

Comment: Have a look at the output and then a closer look at your quotes.

Comment: i have checked it like a thousand times... am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are. The output should contain the literal `base64_encode( $thumbs )` instead as you’ve mixed up the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're trying to do this:

```
$search_output .= "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode( $thumbs ) . "\" /><a href='".$link."'>".$title."</a> - $body<br>";}
```

Comment: thanks @gumbo 200K rep amazing the most ive seen thx bestprogrammerinthework

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments:

```
$search_output .= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode( $thumbs ) .'" /><a href="'.$link.'">'.$title.'</a> - '.$body.'<br>';
```